# Deploying Maven project - Unable to add jersey archetype

Tags: java, maven

I want to set up a environment to write a `RESTful` web service program. Using **RedHat JBOSS developer studio,** I was trying to create.

`File --> New Project --> Maven Project --> Next(skipping workspace) --> Select an archetype`.
I need to select jersey archetype, which is not listing in the 'all catalogs' , I have added the following URL using remote method to download the jersey.

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

Getting this error when I am adding manually.
Manually adding

```
Can't resolve Archetype org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-     webapp:2.23.2
    org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not resolve artifact      org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:pom:2.23.2
Attaching the snapshot for clear understanding.
```

Please help me to sort this.

Comment: You have to make the archetype setting point to network location http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml and then create new project specifying the archetype

Comment: @Ravi.Kumar I have tried with the above mentioned solution. Its listing out nothing after adding the remote catalog URL.

Answer (score 0):

Is your network blocking access to above URL ?

Comment: No, After adding the URL, Its retrieving for sometime and ends up with none without any error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try find jar file in other source and add to project.